# Ubuntu 17.10 randomly freezes

Tags: gnome, 17.10

I've just installed Ubuntu 17.10, because it has `xserver 1.19.x` and up to date kernels for nvidia prime synch for my dedicated card in my laptop.

But it keeps randomly freezing. Mouse moves, but can't interact with anything. Everything is frozen, no keyboard commands respond. I have to hard restart my laptop.

I had issues with prime sync not working, so after contacting support I've disabled Wayland and use `xorg`, now it finally does and I have no screen tear issues. 
(in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`  uncomment the line `#WaylandEnable=false`)

I've read in a similar problem that it's maybe because of gnome wanting wayland?

I have gnome extension installed as well. Tweak tool and Ark theme, Paper Icon pack.

Can I fix this by changing from gnome to something else? Is it supported in 17.10?

What can I do to stop this issue?

Comment: Try to write down the exact time when problem occurs. Then after rebooting, `cd /etc/log` (the logs folder) then `ls -tl` to sort by time (newest first) and see which log files have been updated since the time of the issue. Then look in those 5 or so files and find messages from at or near the time your system froze (each line starts with a timestamp). Then paste those in your question and/or search the web with the likely errors.

Comment: Does everything work if you use different video drivers (or the default drivers)?

Comment: Rather than mess around with `/etc/log/`, you can get the aggregated system logs from `journald`, which provides a more featured interface:

`$ journalctl -xe`

Answer (score 0):

So, after switching to another flavour of Ubuntu this problem was gone (mostly).

I'm using Kubuntu (KDE) now and I don't experience any freezes. I'll assume this bug was because of GNOME.

I only expeirenced one freeze with KDE, when I installed some 'restoreconf' or similar package...don't quite remember. Uninstalled it, the problem was gone. I think that package comes with ubuntu gnome version by default and not with kde...not sure.

But I'll leave this here. If you have freeze problems with GNOME if you disable wayland, switch to another DE and it should be gone. Really disappointed how unstable it is.